# process Axios POST in PHP

Tags: php, axios

I want to send a POST request to my PHP file to handle it and store the data in the database.. I'm pretty stuck at it since $_POST stays empty whatever I try..

Can someone help me sending a post request and help me how to handle it ?

My axios request:

```
// Performing a POST request
axios.post('dev/api/post.php',{ text: text, unk: unk})
  .then(function(response){
      console.log(response);
}).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
});
```

And this is what I kinda tried in PHP, some code is commented out because not sure if it worked..

```
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
/*  
$jsonReceiveData = json_encode($_POST);
$json_output = json_decode($jsonReceiveData);
$task = $json_ouput->text;
$uniquekey = $json_output->unk;
*/
echo $_POST;
/*
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO todo (id, tekst, uniquekey) VALUES ('', :tekst, :unk)");
$stmt->bindParam(':unk', '1');
$stmt->bindParam(':tekst','testing');
$stmt->execute();
*/
```

}

SOLUTION:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
$task = $data['text'];
```

The object was found in php://input

Comment: your axios request syntax seems correct, assuming { text: text, unk: unk} tetxt and unk have data in them, is your api endpoint correct?

Comment: $_POST is an array, echo won't work, try to print_r($_POST)

Comment: @David Probably my endpoint isn't correct, but how to handle the JSON object in PHP that Axios posted ? I don't know how to acces it in PHP

Comment: Your question needs edit, its an issue in your PHP code not React or Axios

Answer (score 17):

The user solved it "finding" the object in **php://input**

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
$task = $data['text'];
```

As pointed by [STEEL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/942317/steel), it was an issue at the PHP code, not React or Axios.

Comment: that is correct..thnx

Answer (score -7):

Just need:

```
if(isset($_POST['text'])) { ... }
```